# fetch Bunch of data from server to Local Db While Opening the android app, without Affecting UI thread(App is not Responding Error)

Tags: android, multithreading, sqlite, android-asynctask, retrofit

1. i am fetching Bunch of d**ata from server to Local Database** ,after Login.
2. its getting some times **Alert App is not Responding Wait or Close.**

Please help me any other Possible way or try to fix this issue.

**Async call:**

```
Asynctask_GetServerData task=new Asynctask_GetServerData ();
   task.execute();
```

**Asynctask Class:**

```
public class Asynctask_GetServerData extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Void>
    {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
            super.onPreExecute();

            if (!pDialog.isShowing())
            {
                pDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
                pDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
                pDialog.setMessage("Please Wait Getting Data...");
                pDialog.show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid)
        {

            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... params)
        {
            getLoginDataCall();

            return null;
        }
    }


    private void getLoginDataCall() {


                sisClient.getApi().getAllData(
                        new Callback<CommonResponse>() {
                            @Override
                            public void success(CommonResponse commonResponse, Response response) {

                                Timber.d("sendOtpAPICall%s", commonResponse.getStatusCode());

                                switch (commonResponse.getStatusCode()) {
                                    case 200:


                                        try {


                                            JSONArray jsonarray = null;
                                            try {
                                                jsonarray = new JSONArray(commonResponse.getRouteMaster());

                                                if (!commonResponse.getRouteMaster().equals("[]")) 
                                                 {
                                                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) 
                                                      {
                                                        JSONObject jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);


                                                        RouteId_StringValue = jsonobject.getString("RouteId");



                                                        Asynxfor_Route_Master_insert(RouteId_StringValue);


                                                    }
                                                } else {
                                                    System.out.println("ROute Master Is NULL ::" + commonResponse.getStatusMessage() + "\n");
                                                }
                                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                                e.printStackTrace();
                                                ;
                                            }

                                      break;

                                    case 404:

                                        pDialog.dismiss();
                                        Toast.makeText(LoginPage.this, R.string.wrong_Username_or_password, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                        break;
                                    case 500:
                                        pDialog.dismiss();
                                        Toast.makeText(LoginPage.this, R.string.something_wrong, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        break;

                                }
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void failure(RetrofitError error) {

                                try {
                                    if (error != null) {
                                        pDialog.dismiss();
                                        Timber.i("sendOtpAPICall error %s", error.getResponse().getStatus());
                                        String json = new String(((TypedByteArray) error.getResponse().getBody()).getBytes());
                                        Timber.i("failure  error %s", json.toString());

                                        JSONObject json1 = new JSONObject(json.toString());
                                        String json1string = json1.getString("StatusMessage");


                                        switch (error.getResponse().getStatus()) {
                                            case 404:
                                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.wrong_Username_or_password, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                                break;
                                            case 500:
                                                Toast.makeText(LoginPage.this, R.string.something_wrong, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                                break;
                                            default:
                                                Toast.makeText(LoginPage.this, json1string, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                                break;
                                        }


                                    } else {
                                        Timber.i("failure  error %s", "Recieving error null rom server");
                                    }


                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                    Toast.makeText(LoginPage.this, R.string.something_wrong, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }


                            }

                        });

            }
```

Comment: Well it is not ok using an AsycTask in your case as getAllData already uses an onResponse() handler and takes care for a thread itself. So call getAllData directly.

Comment: i want Progress Dialog that why i kept inside Async task.

Comment: You now know that it is impossible to use an AsyncTask. So invent something else. A ProgressDialog can also be created outside an AsyncTask.

Comment: outside  asynctask Progressdialog will not Affect my UI thread?

Comment: Of course it will. But what does it matter? The user should look at the progress as you want him to do that. Having said that i wonder why you would not do all in the background.